# Flutter Apple Sign in not get email,password, and name,surname

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

the code below allows you to login with apple-id but I can't see the credentials, why?

**Flutter Code:**

```
  final credentialUser = await SignInWithApple
                                  .getAppleIDCredential(
                                  scopes: AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.values);
                              print(credentialUser);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this


 final credential = await SignInWithApple.getAppleIDCredential(
  scopes: [
    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.email,
    AppleIDAuthorizationScopes.fullName,
  ],
);
```

Comment: same result not change anything